# Python Pandas groupby based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes with a common index. I would like to group `df1` based on a subset of columns in `df2`.

I know how to groupby multiple columns already in `df1`, like `df1.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])` and I know how to group on a different series with the same index, like `df1.groupby(df2['col1'])`. Is there an immediate way to do something like

```
>>> df1.groupby(df[['col1', 'col2']])
# ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

Of course, I could do

```
df1.groupby([df2['col1'], df2['col2']])
```

but it seems there should be a more direct syntax for this. (Imagine having several grouping columns, etc.)

Comment: groupby series not dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
gbobj = pd.concat([df1, df2[['col1','col2']], axis=1).groupby(['col1','col2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be either `merge`, `join` or `concat` the two dataframes and then group or a "more direct syntax" using a list comprehension, e.g:

```
many_grouping_columns = ['A', 'B', ...]  # columns found in in df2
df1.groupby([df2[col] for col in many_grouping_columns])
```